# Peut-on établir un lien quelconque entre "mousse" et "moissine" ?

Tags: étymologie

Peut-on supposer que l'origine étymologique de *mousse* et de *moissine* est identique ?

On trouve dans le *Littré* :

[**mousse**](https://www.littre.org/definition/mousse) : Berry, mosse ; provenç. mos ; ital. mozzo ; du germanique : rhétique, mutt, mutsch, émoussé ; moy. Haut all. mutzen, mutiler ; holl. mots, émoussé. Le radical germanique paraît être le même que dans le latin mut-ilus, mutilé.

[**moissine**](https://www.littre.org/definition/moissine) : La forme du mot indique un latin fictif mustina, dérivé de mustum, moût, ou plutôt de mustus, frais, récent : la branche fraîche ; le changement de st en ss n'est pas rare.

Je me permets de poser cette question parce que malgré l'origine germanique commune (mutt/mustum/mustus) attestée dans le *Littré*, le *Dictionnaire du Moyen Français* donne *mosa* comme la racine étymologique de [*mousse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/mousse) et *musteus* comme racine étymologique de [*moissine*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/moissine).

Peut-on affirmer que l’étymologie ou les anciennes graphies de ces deux termes permettent d’établir un lien quelconque entre *mousse* et *moissine* ?

Comment: It's tough. The first word is essentially extinct with this meaning (but survives in *émoussé*) and the second one is hyper specialized and very rare. The last links are broken too. I guess you want https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mousse/3 and https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moissine

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi j'ai écrit mon commentaire en anglais...

Comment: Je vous remercie tout de même !

Answer (score 1):

Le DMF donne ***mosa*** comme racine étymologique de ***mousse***, mais il ne s'agit pas du même mot.

L'acception n°1 du DMF est celle du végétal nommé ***mousse*** (substantif) alors que l'acception n°1 de ***mousse*** du Littré correspond un adjectif, **émoussé** en français moderne.

***Mosa*** n'a donc rien à voir avec cet adjectif et il faut regarder l'acception n°3 du DMF pour trouver l'étymologie ***Muttiu*** qui correspond au rhétique ***Mutt***.

Quant à ***moissine***, son étymologie est inconnue [d'après le TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/moissine):

> MOISSINE, sustantif féminin
> **Étymologie et Historique** XIII<sup>e</sup>s. [date du manuscrit] (*Bible*, B.N. 899, fo60 d ds Gdf.). Mot d'origine inconnue (*Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch* t.22, 2, p.72a). D'après Sainéan *Autour des sources indigènes* t.1, p.141 il serait à rapprocher de l'ancien français *meschine* « jeune fille », attesté sous la forme *moichine* dans *Floovant* (v. T.-L.), ce qui paraît tout à fait invraisemblable. *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der französischen Sprache* rattache dubitativement *moissine* au latin *musteus* « doux comme du moût ». *Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch, loc. cit.* signale l'existence de *mousse de sep* attesté au sens de « jeune bourgeon de la vigne qui doit produire le fruit » (1664, Duez, *Dict. français-allemand-latin*) et qui est peut-être à mettre en rapport avec *moissine*.